# Statements true regarding roots using rolles/mean value theorem and its converse

Tags: calculus, functions

Below are the statements (all roots are meant to be real ) :
A) If $f(x)$ is function on R ->R has n roots then surely $f'(x)$ will be having n-1 roots .                    B) If $f'(x)$ is a function on $R->R$ and is zero at three points then $f(x)$ will have same zero atmost four points  .                        C) If $f(x)$ is a polynomial then $f(x)$ will have atmost n roots if $f''(x)$ has $n-2$ roots . $f(x)$ roots may be $n-2$ or $n-1$ or $n$ .               D)If $f(x)$ is a function having derivative zero at some points its not guaranteed at all that $f(x)$ should be having any root at all .

> My progress : in case of polynomial we are bound to have roots if $f(x)$ has n roots then by applying rolles to it we can say f'(x) will have surely n-1 roots but the converse is not true we might be having same values in the $f(x)$ in some places instead of zero and still we get $f'(x)$  zero in between those points . So possibility of $f(x)$ is that it can have any real roots from 0 to n if $f'(x)$ has n-1 roots. In case of a general function i am not able to conclude very well will it be like the polynomial case only ? I think option A and D are true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A) Let $f(x)=e^{x^{2}}$ then $f$ has no root but $f'(x)=2xe^{x^{2}}$ has one root. So A0 is false.
B) This depends on how you interpret the hypothesis. If $f'(x)$ is zero at exatly three points then the conclusion holds by Rolle's Theorem.  Otherwise, $f\equiv 0$ would be a counter-example to B).

C) The first part is again true by Rolles' Theorem. For the second part consider the following examples:

$f(x)=1+x^{2}$ with $n=2$. Here $f$ has $n-2$ roots. This is easy.

$f(x)=x^{4}-1$ with $n=3$ . Here $f''(x)$ has $n-2=1$ root and $f(x)$ has $n-1=2$ roots (namely $\pm 1$).

I will let you construct an example where $f$ has $n$ roots.

D) is true: Take $f(x)=e^{x^{2}}$

Comment: I understood everything except one should nt real roots of x^4 - 1 be n =2 only ? Other two are imaginary how n=3?

Comment: The real roots of $x^{4}-1=(x-1)(x+1)(x^{2}+1)$ are $+1$ and $-1$.

Comment: Oh i misunderstood that its was you were giving example for **atmost** 3 one , okay got it